# Self Join query on cascading results

Tags: sql, select, self-join

I am having problem in framing one sql query.
I need to select all records based on Transaction ID as I explained below

1. Assume user given transaction TX444, I need to fetch all records with Child Id = Parent Id of given transaction AND Parent_Id = Child_Id of already selected records.

So if I give TRansaction as TX444, all records shown should be selected.

1. Assume user given Transaction = TX234, then I need to fetch all records with Child Id = Parent Id of given transaction AND Parent_Id = Child_Id of already selected records.
   in this case last record will not be included.

I am trying to write SELECT query. But nothing is working :(

```
PARENT_ID       CHILD_ID                   TRANSACTION        STATE
1               4                           TX123           PF
2               4                           TX128           PS
3               5                           TX230           FF
4               5                           TX234           FS
5               0                           TX444           DS
```

I am not SQL person, but I need to make this up

Comment: What DBMS are you using?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Oracle you can use [CONNECT BY](http://psoug.org/reference/connectby.html) to recursively loop through rows:

```
SELECT  Parent_ID, 
        Child_ID, 
        Transaction, 
        State,
        CASE Level WHEN 1 THEN 'Selected' ELSE 'Child' END AS Relation
FROM    Transactions
START WITH Transaction = 'TX444'
CONNECT BY PRIOR Child_ID = Parent_ID
UNION
SELECT  Parent_ID, 
        Child_ID, 
        Transaction, 
        State,
        CASE Level WHEN 1 THEN 'Selected' ELSE 'Parent' END AS Relation
FROM    Transactions
START WITH Transaction = 'TX444'
CONNECT BY PRIOR Parent_ID = Child_ID;
```

I've put an example on **[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/2c178/15)**, but I've used slightly different children/parents to your data to fully show how you can use `CONNECT BY` not just to get the parents/children, but also to determine what generation each is.